# ng2-charts - Display only monday's date on x-axis of linechart

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I am using ng2-charts with angular 6.

I have used line chart which displays value on y-axis and dates on x-axis.

[Line chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9LQU.png)

So my requirement is like show dates of monday's only on x-axis. Still on hover of data point on chart it should show me date with value, only x-axis labels change needed.

## HTML Code

```
<canvas baseChart [colors]="lineChartColors" [datasets]="labelMFL" [labels]="lineChartLabels"
    [options]="lineChartOptions" [chartType]="'line'">
```

## TS Code

```
public labelMFL: Array<any> = [{
  data: [20, 8, 49, 38, 34, 54, 10, 20, 8, 49, 38, 34, 54, 10],
  label: 'ng2'
}];

public lineChartLabels: Array<any> = ['2020-07-13', '2020-07-14', '2020-07-15', '2020-07-16', '2020-07-17','2020-07-18','2020-07-19','2020-07-20','2020-07-21','2020-07-22','2020-07-23','2020-07-24','2020-07-25','2020-07-26']; 

public lineChartColors: Color[] = [{ // grey
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
  borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
  pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
  pointBorderColor: '#fff',
  pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
  pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
}];

public lineChartOptions: any = {
responsive: true,
scales : {
  yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      max : 60,
      min : 0,
    }
  }],
  xAxes: [{}],
},
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not clear. Share your code.

Comment: @uiTeam324, i have added code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display only monday's date on x-axis, add following config in options:

```
xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    time: {
      unit: 'week',
      isoWeekday: true,
      tooltipFormat: 'D MMM',
      displayFormats: {
        week: 'D MMM'
      }
    }
  }],
```